# Qual a melhor maneira de realizar a gravação de um log dos usuários?

Tags: mysql, txt, log

Tenho um pequeno sistema de monitoramento que tem o intuito de mostrar se os dados de alguns servidores estão iguais aos *backups*.

Como o sistema interage diretamente com o banco de dados, surgiu a necessidade de saber quem acessava e quando acessavam o sistema, como sou novo na área de programação, minha primeira alternativa foi montar uma função que guardava o nome, o IP, a ação do usuário junto com a data/hora que o usuário executou a ação em um banco de dados MySQL.

Vi que existem outras opções, gravando em `txt` por exemplo, porém, gravando os acessos em MySQL, fica muito mais fácil de manipulá-los para uso estatístico e afins.

Estou fazendo da maneira certa? Existe outra forma de fazer isso que seja tão efetiva quanto essa? Qual o problema de fazer dessa forma? Depende da quantidade de acessos?

Comment: Vejo que o uso de *Triggers* é a maneira mais segura de se manter um *log* de alterações num banco. Um problema natural é que dependendo do número de alterações que um banco sofre, a tabela de Logs crescerá exponencialmente.  
Depende também quais informações as *trigger´s* irão salvar.. (todos os campos? em todas operações? em todas tabelas?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só você pode responder o que é melhor para você. Realmente é muito mais fácil fazer no MySQL e totalmente viável, até servidores HTTP usam isto, ainda que não por padrão.

Fazendo em um arquivo pode ser mais performático. E não deve ser difícil importar para um banco de dados para manipular *offline*. Claro que precisa tomar alguns cuidados.

Se precisar que o log seja transacional com o que foi feito aí na prática o banco de dados se torna a única opção.

Comment: Até o momento eu estou usando o Mysql, e atende perfeitamente bem, o sistema não costuma ter tantos acessos assim, em duas semanas tive 15 mil interações, oq é um numero baixo até, mas como não sou tão experiente na área, fiquei em duvida se isso é uma boa pratica ou não

Comment: Absurdamente baixo. A diferença de performance raramente será relevante e mesmo se for tem técnicas para evitar atrapalhar muito. O pessoal usa o tempo todo, até os servidores HTTP tem opção para *logar* no DB.

Comment: Ah sim, que ótimo, a tendencia é que o numero de acessos cresça, por isso fiquei preocupado, mas como a tendencia é que esses logs durem no máximo um ano fico mais tranquilo, em caso de emergência/desespero recorrerei ao Forum novamente kkkk, muito obrigado, abraço